# Adding a seperator for each system queried? Custom Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am having trouble trying to understand the logic behind my code to get it working properly. Just a quick script I've got, to retrieve Software Versions from a remote system and getting the output into a `[PSCustomObject]`.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$NetBIOSNames   = @('ComputerOne','ComputerTwo')
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$softwareNames  = @("ActivClient","Adobe Acrobat", "ATHOC", "DSET", "Firefox", "Google Chrome", "Java", "McAfee Agent")
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$VersionNumber  = @() 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$CorrectVersion = @('7.2.1','21.001.20138','6.2.27.271','1.6.8','78.8.0','89.0.4389.72','8.0.2710.9','5.7.1.116')

foreach($Computer in $NetBIOSNames){
    foreach ($software in $softwareNames) {
        $Version = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { 
            Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
                Where-Object {$_.displayname -like "*$Using:software*" } 
        }

        $null    = $VersionNumber.Add($($Version.DisplayVersion))
    }

    For($i=0; $i -lt $softwareNames.Count; $i++){

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Computer Name"    = $NetBIOSNames[$i]
            "Software Name"    = $softwareNames[$i]
            "Current Version"  = $VersionNumber[$i]
            "Correct Version"  = $CorrectVersion[$i]
        }
    }
}
```

So, when ran against a single computer it returns the following which is the desired output:

```
Computer Name   Software Name Current Version          Correct Version
-------------   ------------- ---------------          ---------------
ComputerOne     ActivClient   7.2.1                    7.2.1          
                Adobe Acrobat 21.001.20138             21.001.20138   
                ATHOC         6.2.27.271               6.2.27.271     
                DSET          1.6.8                    1.6.8          
                Firefox       78.8.0                   78.8.0         
                Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72             89.0.4389.72   
                Java          {8.0.2710.9, 8.0.2710.9} 8.0.2710.9     
                McAfee Agent  {5.7.1.116, 5.7.1.116}   5.7.1.116
```

….but, when running against multiple it returns this:

```
Computer Name   Software Name Current Version          Correct Version
-------------   ------------- ---------------          ---------------
ComputerOne     ActivClient   7.2.1                    7.2.1          
ComputerTwo     Adobe Acrobat 21.001.20138             21.001.20138   
                ATHOC         6.2.27.271               6.2.27.271     
                DSET          1.6.8                    1.6.8          
                Firefox       78.8.0                   78.8.0         
                Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72             89.0.4389.72   
                Java          {8.0.2710.9, 8.0.2710.9} 8.0.2710.9     
                McAfee Agent  {5.7.1.116, 5.7.1.116}   5.7.1.116      
ComputerOne     ActivClient   7.2.1                    7.2.1          
ComputerTwo     Adobe Acrobat 21.001.20138             21.001.20138   
                ATHOC         6.2.27.271               6.2.27.271     
                DSET          1.6.8                    1.6.8          
                Firefox       78.8.0                   78.8.0         
                Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72             89.0.4389.72   
                Java          {8.0.2710.9, 8.0.2710.9} 8.0.2710.9     
                McAfee Agent  {5.7.1.116, 5.7.1.116}   5.7.1.116
```

What i'd like to return is the following:

```
Computer Name   Software Name Current Version          Correct Version
-------------   ------------- ---------------          ---------------
ComputerOne     ActivClient   7.2.1                    7.2.1          
                Adobe Acrobat 21.001.20138             21.001.20138   
                ATHOC         6.2.27.271               6.2.27.271     
                DSET          1.6.8                    1.6.8          
                Firefox       78.8.0                   78.8.0         
                Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72             89.0.4389.72   
                Java          {8.0.2710.9, 8.0.2710.9} 8.0.2710.9     
                McAfee Agent  {5.7.1.116, 5.7.1.116}   5.7.1.116
      
ComputerTwo     ActivClient   7.2.1                    7.2.1          
                Adobe Acrobat 21.001.20138             21.001.20138   
                ATHOC         6.2.27.271               6.2.27.271     
                DSET          1.6.8                    1.6.8          
                Firefox       78.8.0                   78.8.0         
                Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72             89.0.4389.72   
                Java          {8.0.2710.9, 8.0.2710.9} 8.0.2710.9     
                McAfee Agent  {5.7.1.116, 5.7.1.116}   5.7.1.116
```

Pardon for this being a long post. Just kind of stuck on what im not doing right. I figured it's the way I'm enumerating through my `[PSCustomObject]` but, not really sure on how to go about it. Anyone got an idea, or better suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: WHY are you gathering the info, saving parts of it into different collections, AND THEN merging it back into one? [*grin*] build your PSCO immediately, not after chopping it up. ///// run your `Invoke-Command` call against the list of systems, use a scriptblock to gather ALL the wanted info, build your PSCO on the target system with that info ... and then send that back to your calling system.

Comment: Yep, I agree with above suggestion. You can also do this to gather the item properties: `(Get-ItemProperty @('HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*')).where({$using:softwareNames -match $_.displayName})` instead of looping $softwareNames.

Comment: I agree as well, think im just overthinking it.

Comment: I think you could combine `$softwareNames` and `$correctVersion` into a hashtable or PSObject. You can use that object later as map to compare what there is on remote servers against it.

Comment: The *"Current Version"* is the return of the remote PC, I just might go about this completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do: declaring the object with properties and append it to the array

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$NetBIOSNames   = @('ComputerOne','ComputerTwo')
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$softwareNames  = @("ActivClient",,"Adobe Acrobat", "ATHOC", "DSET", "Firefox", "Google Chrome", "Java", "McAfee Agent")
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$VersionNumber  = @() 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$CorrectVersion = @('7.2.1','21.001.20138','6.2.27.271','1.6.8','78.8.0','89.0.4389.72','8.0.2710.9','5.7.1.116')

$computerList = @()
foreach($Computer in $NetBIOSNames){
    $computerObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Computer Name"    = ""
        Software           = [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Software Name"    = ""
            "Current Version"  = ""
            "Correct Version"  = ""
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $softwareNames.Count; $i++){
        $Version = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
            Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.displayname -like "*$($args[0])*"}
        } -ArgumentList $softwareNames[$i]
        $computerObj.Software.'Software Name' = $softwareNames[$i]
        $computerObj.Software.'Current Version' = $Version.DisplayVersion
        $computerObj.Software.'Correct Version' = $CorrectVersion[$i]
        $VersionNumber += $computerObj
    }
}
```

With this, you just need to print `$VersionNumber` array of objects holding all info required

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would personally do, creating the PSObject in the remote servers makes sense to me. Also `Invoke-Command` to the array of computers is a lot faster than looping each computer.

One thing I should mention is that, the hashtable keys should be the exact Display Names.

```
$NetBIOSNames = 'ComputerOne','ComputerTwo' # I always encourage using ArrayList // GenericList but for an array of computers is not much needed.

$scriptBlock={
    
    $regPaths=@(
        'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    )
    
    $softwareMap = @{
        'ActivClient'='7.2.1'
        'Adobe Acrobat'='21.001.20138'
        'ATHOC'='6.2.27.271'
        'DSET'='1.6.8'
        'Firefox'='78.8.0'
        'Google Chrome'='89.0.4389.72'
        'Java'='8.0.2710.9'
        'McAfee Agent'='5.7.1.116'
    }

    $itemProps = Get-ItemProperty $regPaths | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -iin $softwareMap.Keys}

    foreach($item in $itemProps)
    {
        $correctVersion = $softwareMap[$item.DisplayName]

        [pscustomobject]@{
            'Computer Name' = $env:COMPUTERNAME # Definetly reccommend populating this prop for all Objects, easier to filter in Excel :)
            'Software Name' = $item.DisplayName
            'Current Version' = $item.DisplayVersion -join ', '
            'Correct Version' = $correctVersion
            'Correct Version (Bool)' = $CorrectVersion -in $item.DisplayVersion # Using -in in case DisplayVersion is an array. Having a Bool for your Excel is also nice to have.
        }
    }
}

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $NetBIOSNames -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -HideComputerName

$result[0] #> Here is the PSObject of Computer 1
```